# Is XCOPY the fastest tool to copy folders/files over Windows file system?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems, xcopy

I have a maintenance task to copy folders from one server to another.
the source folder is big - roughly ~Ks of files / 5-6 tree levels and overall size of ~1GB.

I was using Robocopy.exe and XCOPY.exe from windows command line and their performance is fair, and i wonder if there a faster tool to deliver the task.

of course the actual performance is highly dependend on network overload, but i believe the test cases use the same environment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming in any way.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'Callback I'm a programmer, and I just faced the same problem, and this question and the answer probably just saved me hours.

Comment: @szmate1618: if you find the Q and A useful - upvote them :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Robocopy's speed depends on some options.

/Z option copies files in restart mode. When network goes down while copying, it resume next time. BUT with this option speed is not good.

/MT Creates multi-threaded copies with N threads. N must be an integer between 1 and 128. The default value for N is 8.

Since you have ~Ks of files and local network, try to use more than default 8 threads (around 25) without /Z parameter.

Also supressing file output increase speed.

```
robocopy source destination /MT:25 /NP /NFL /NDL
```

/NFL No file list - don't log file names

/NDL No directory list - don't log directory names

With these options we copy millions of files with size above 1TB, and it can utilize all 1Gbit/sec network, so the limit is your network speed as you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about not using the /Z flag - it made a huge difference on a slow WAN!

Comment: did realise that robocopy came with Windows